# How to Sha1 key from keystore for release mode? Java JDK 11 for windows 10

Tags: android-studio, sha1, android-keystore

I'm setting up a new app and I need that to authenticate with firebase. I have tried a lot of different codes to get SHA1 key but I am unable to do so. Please help me.

[Checkout the image please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPD7L.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get **SHA1** for your app using **Signing Reports** option from your IDE. Please check image below.

> **Please note:**

You will have to mention your keystore details and create a signing config in project settings / Gradle file. once your signing config is added, using this option you will be able to get SHA1 for signed apk as well. Otherwise there will be SHA1 for Debug config.

[image]

**Result as :**

[image]